Embedding using the LangChain_AWS is giving None value
I am trying to embed a text using the langchain_aws BedrockEmbeddings, but when I invoke the function, I get a list with the None values.
Here's the code:
from langchain_community.llms.bedrock import Bedrock 
from langchain_aws import BedrockEmbeddings
import boto3

# Initialize the Bedrock client
bedrock_client = boto3.client(service_name='bedrock-runtime')

# Initialize Bedrock Embeddings
bedrock_embeddings = BedrockEmbeddings(
    model_id="amazon.titan-text-express-v1",
    credentials_profile_name="default",
    client=bedrock_client,
    region_name="ap-south-1"
)


embed_data=bedrock_embeddings.embed_documents(["This is a content of the document", "This is another document"])

print(embed_data)


Output:
[None, None]


amazon.titan-text-express-v1 is not embedding model. Its a text generation model.
Use amazon.titan-embed-text-v2:0

The provided model identifier is invalid. The above model ID is unavailable on AWS Bedrock. I want to implement document embedding using llama3 or Amazon Titan using AWS Bedrock, but implementing anyone gives me an error or None value. If anyone has suggestions to create embedding from scratch or recommended library. I would love to appreciate

Thanks, Arindam above model is available in a different region N. Virginia and Oregon
